# Displaying Google Map/Streetview on webpage with a dynamic address

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm trying to display a google map on a webpage. The address that the map displays is dynamic. I'm getting the address from a database. Is there anyway to use this address and display it on a webpage? 
I followed this tutorial with no luck: http://www.thetutorialblog.com/php/php-class-for-google-maps-api/

If anyone has any other links or suggestions i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994424/google-maps-geocoding-address-to-glatlng) that does the geocoding on the client.  The only thing your php would have to do is provide the address string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this [PHP Google Map API](http://code.google.com/p/php-google-map-api/), which appears to be a fork/update of the API talked about in the tutorial that you used.  The [demos](http://code.google.com/p/php-google-map-api/#Demos) look pretty clear.